# Is there a way to find the center of a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, centering

I want my text to be in the middle of the browser window, is there any way I can find (in pixels) the middle of the browser? This isn't just HTML text, so I can't use CSS or anything. Here's part of my code in case you don't understand my confusing explanation:

```
<canvas id = "my-canvas" width = "screen.width" height = "screen.height"></canvas>
        

        <script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/processing.js/1.4.8/processing.min.js"></script>
        <script type = "application/javascript">
            // program code {
                var sketchProc = function(processingInstance) {
                    with (processingInstance) {
                        background(255);
                        fill(0);
                        text("Hi", 300, 300);
                    } 
                };
            // }
            // store canvas {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("my-canvas");
            // }
            // run Processing.js {
                var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);
            // }
        </script>
```

Comment: Did you mean to say This IS just HTML text? And you say you can't use CSS "or anything" but you tagged "javascript". Can you show what you've done and what you expect to happen

Comment: No, I'm using a dead API called Processing.

Comment: It is technically in HTML.

Comment: I edited my comment to contain some of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for ya

```
const width = window.innerWidth / 2;
const height = window.innerHeight / 2;
text("Hi", width, height);
```